# Call/execute another page in php

Tags: php, include

I'm trying to call another php page without having one after the other.

I have pages `a` and `b`:

- `a.php` contains:

  ```
  <html a page tags>
  <?php echo "i'm a.php"; ?>
  </html a page tags>
  ```
- `b.php` contains:

  ```
  <html b page tags>
  <?php 
    echo "i'm b.php";
    include '../a.php';
  ?>
  </html b tags>
  ```

When `b.php` is run, it displays:

```
    <html b page tags>
    i'm b.php
    <html a page tags>
    i'm a.php
    </html a page tags>
    </html b tags>
```

You can see html tags from both `a` and `b`, one after the other.

Instead, when `b.php` is run it *should display only the text* within `a`'s html tags. I.e., the output should be:

```
    <html b page tags>
    i'm b.php
    i'm a.php
    </html b tags>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to put `HTML` tag in a.php if it's always included. meaning this:

a.php

```
<?php echo "i'm a.php"; ?>
```

b.php

```
<html b page tags>
<?php 
    echo "i'm b.php";
    include '../a.php';
?>
</html b tags>
```

html output:

```
<html b page tags>
    i'm b.php
    i'm a.php
</html b tags>
```

Comment: Hi i guess i have a misunderstanding how the web/php works. I'm a trying to make a simple contact form b.php and a.php is the thank you page. All the logic and validation is in b.php, a.php it's just the message. Both have similar html tags. If I do your method i don't see a.php in the url textbox. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a.php to run by itself, just remove html tags from a.php.

If you want a.php and b.php can run separately, you can do it like this.

a.php

```
<?php if (isset($being_included)): ?>
<html a page tags>
<? endif; ?>

<?php echo "i'm a.php"; ?>

<?php if (isset($being_included)): ?>
</html a page tags>
<? endif; ?>
```

b.php

```
<html b page tags>
<?php 
    echo "i'm b.php";
    $being_included = true;
    include '../a.php';
?>
</html b tags>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

nice question :)

**a.php**

```
<html a page tgas>
<?php echo "i'm a.php"; ?>
</html a page tgas>
```

**b.php**

```
<html b page tags>
 <?php 
    echo "i'm b.php";
 ?>
</html b tags>
<?php
require'../a.php'; // incase it doesnt execute it will give you error telling WHY??
?>
```

It will keep both the page tag intact and will give you the output as you want..

**on clicking b.php**

```
  <html b page tags>
  i'm b.php
  </html b tags>

  <html a page tags>
    i'm a.php
  </html a tags>
```

Comment: your welcome.. there are any ways to say thanks too on stackoverflow if it helped you.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I used header... I was missing something you have to put the php tag first before the html

```
   <html>
   </html>
   <?php
      //this will NOT work, the browser received the HTML tag before the script
      header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' ) ;
   ?>
```

As indicated here: http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/ht/phpredirection.htm

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late :

I use `echo file_get_contents(" URL ");`

this shows only the output, if the site is a script , this script is run on the remote server.